# What happens when an RDP session times out?

Tags: terminal-server, windows-server-2003, session

When a RDP sessions time out, what happens to the running processes? Are they gracefully shutdown, and if that fails then forcefully terminated?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the settings on the Terminal Server. Specfically the Session settings for RDP connections. Provided you have appropriate permissions to access them, they can be accessed via

```
Administrative Tools > Terminal Services Configuration > Connections
```

You can configure it to end disconnected sessions immediately, or after a certain time, or never.

Have a read here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779468(WS.10).aspx

If the session is configured to end, the result will essentially be the same as logging out.

Comment: And when the session is to be terminated intimidate it operates about the same was as if you had used the logout function.

Comment: -1 - The OP wanted to know what actually happens when the session is terminated due to those settings, not how to set the timeouts

Comment: Since you have to specify what the action should be when time outs this seems correct to me

Answer (score 1):

The processes keep running.  Try running a ping -t 127.0.0.1, disconnect and then reconnect.  You will see that the ping command is still running.

Not that it will make any difference, but if you want to simulate a time out, then disable your network card after you start the ping command.

Comment: Disconnecting your network card simulates a disconnected session.  It does not simulate a session that was terminated because of a session limit timeout.